# Mail-form submits, even after validation fail

Tags: jquery, html, validation

Trying to get this code to run with a simple validation check on a submit form. The error message pops-up but the form still gets submitted. Could anyone point me in the correct direction.

```js
function validateForm() {
  //Validate Name
  var title = $("#name").val();
  if (title == "" || title == null) {
    alert("Please enter");
    return false;
  }
  //Validate Title
  var title = $("#title").val();
  if (title == "" || title == null) {
    alert("Please enter");
    return false;
  }
  //Validate Company
  var title = $("#company").val();
  if (title == "" || title == null) {
    alert("Please enter");
    return false;
  }
  // Validate Email
  var email = $("#email").val();
  if ((/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(email)) || email == "" || email == null) {} else {
    alert("Please enter");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="contactform" method="POST" action="contact.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name :" id="name" name="name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Title :" id="title" name="title">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Company :" id="company" name="company">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email :" id="email" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sbmt">
</form>
```

Comment: I placed your logic in to a snippet where it appears to work fine. If the form submission is not being prevented, then it's most likely that there is an error occurring in your JS code and the `return false;` statement is not being hit. Check the console/

Comment: maybe change `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` to `onsubmit="validateForm()"`. or even better: dont use inline javascript.

Comment: What happens if a user has Javascript disabled? Never rely on client-side validation alone, always use server-side validation

Comment: @Alex doing this does not change the result. It still sends the email.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener that prevents the default function, which in this case is to submit a form. That is, `function validateForm(e)` and then add the line `e.preventDefault()` inside the function.

```js
function validateForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Validate Name
  var title = $("#name").val();
  if (title == "" || title == null) {
    alert("Please enter");
    return false;
  }
  //Validate Title
  var title = $("#title").val();
  if (title == "" || title == null) {
    alert("Please enter");
    return false;
  }
  //Validate Company
  var title = $("#company").val();
  if (title == "" || title == null) {
    alert("Please enter");
    return false;
  }
  // Validate Email
  var email = $("#email").val();
  if ((/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(email)) || email == "" || email == null) {} else {
    alert("Please enter");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="contactform" method="POST" action="contact.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name :" id="name" name="name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Title :" id="title" name="title">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Company :" id="company" name="company">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email :" id="email" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sbmt">
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry Antony, this does not work as well. It does the validation when i leave everything blank but it still sends the form. Does this have anything to do with contact.php?